# Savefig saves images with small black and white squares like a chess board

Tags: matplotlib

I am using save fig to save my plots, but it saves the plots with small black and white squares like a chess board.

```
    plt.ion()
    plt.show()
    plt.figure('Amplitude Evolution')
    plt.axis([0, 100, -2, 2])
    plt.scatter(tot, Amp[0,tot])
    print Amp[0,tot]
    plt.draw()
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc=1, borderaxespad=0.)
    plt.title('Amplitude Evolution')
    plt.xlabel('Time[s]',fontsize=25)
    plt.ylabel('Amplitude',fontsize=25)
    plt.savefig("res.png", transparent = True, pad_inches=0)
```

Is it because of scatter and live updated plot?

Comment: plt.savefig() # do it first.
plt.show() # then look if you want.

Comment: no it didn't change anythin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that whatever application you are viewing the file `res.png` with is adding the 'chess board' to indicate transparency. The file itself does not have a 'chess board' in it.

Try placing the file on a white background (e.g. paste it into a Word or Powerpoint document).

Comment: yes it seems that it's due to my linux application that does that, tnx